# Is there any significant benefit of using UMAKE if the user has time to install software from the deb package?

Tags: package-management, 19.04, ubuntu-make

A lot of devs recommend umake to install IDE's over snap, flatpak, etc. But what if a user decides not to choose snap or flatpak and choose tar or deb package to install over umake, is that a dumb move? I had installed IntelliJ Ultimate from .tar file available from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux). I update it [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8HaE.jpg) way using Jetbrains app name Toolbox.

Should I choose Umake over what I am using right now? Is there any increase in speed, decrease in size, etc any benefits of umake apps that I don't know about? Or there is none.

Comment: Please provide a source for "A lot of devs recommend umake to install IDE's over snap, flatpak, etc."

Comment: @DKBose it's on Reddit. Ubuntu Reddit community. (Sorry I wasn't clear on the source.) The main reason for this is the snap package speed in comparison with apt or umake. People don't like snap over there. I have seen many debates. I don't want one overhear. I just one, my question/doubt to answer, "Does umake package is the best over others? Or is it the same?"

Answer (score 0):

One obvious reason, you don't need to install and run the snapd. One process less that consumes CPU/RAM and has potentially security issues.